# Vertical alignment does not work in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to vertically center the menu links of my header, but does not work. I'm using Bootstrap.

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-2" style="font-size: 40px;">
                    <p>Capelli</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <ul class="list-group list-inline">
                        <li>Vestidos</li>
                        <li>Meus Pedidos</li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li>Login</li>
                        <li>Cadastro</li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li>Carrinho</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: #CFCFCF;
}

.header {
    min-height: 3.7em;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #002A43;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.vertical {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

When a run the code, nothing happens.

I've tried many things, like use the class directly in row or in col-, but nothing work. I also trie diferent methods to align vertically, but did not work.

P.S.: Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Pay attention, you are not applying `vertical` to anything, add it to `col-xs-*`. Also, within your `row` your grid sums up to 13 cols - check if that's by design.

Comment: I tried to put the class in the row, but it did not work

Comment: I didnt say to put it in `row`, I said apply it to `div`s with class `col-xs-*`

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a nav bar menu?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Capelli</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav push-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Vestidos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> etc</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">etc</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">etc</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

in css you shoud define the font-size of X pixels, because you are using relative font-size.

its 3.7em of 10px or 20px. depending the browser the value can change.

```
 html{ font-size: 16px;}
.header{font-size: 1.25em; // 20/16 = 1.25 and you have sure the font size is relative to 16 because you have define html font size to 16px;.
```

Comment: But the problem is that the navbar class has a small height, and if I increase it the elements the elements are no longer vertically aligned